What does "bread basket" refer to?
Mob enforcer Jatemme tortures Bobby, a disabled worker at a
bowling alley, to find out why Harry Rawlings stole money from him:

Jatemme: Oh, this is like that old game Operation. You know that old
game?
Bobby: F_ck.
Jatemme: Now, where the bread basket?

It's confusing for me because it could either refer to Bobby's stomach, hinting at the
violence, or the key information Jatemme seeks.
What does "bread basket" refer to?

In the 1960's game "operation", one of the play pieces is:

Bread Basket: A slice of bread and one of the most difficult pieces to remove, with a small notch removed from the top for easier grip ($1,000).

Nothing outside that game gives any hint other than "this is where I'll be stabbing you next time" (or, as tvtropes says it: "puncturing him repeatedly with his knife") unless you tell me what I want to know.
As the bread basket is the most valuable piece of the game, and Jatemme is looking for the money, it seems only logical to take this 1st degree.
In the urban dictionary, "bread basket" is either the belly or the testicles. But I don't think Jatemme is talking about the lower parts in this case.


I seen to recall that 'bread basket' is a play on 'pannus', the overhanging shelf of belly fat. Pannus sound a bit like the French word for bread('pain'), hence that's his bread basket.

@Valorum French and Romance in general as far as I know.

@AntonSherwood - There ain't nothin' romantic about having a great big belly.

@AntonSherwood And Japanese, because they learned about bread from the Portuguese and thus the Japanese word for bread is loaned from Portuguese.

@Valorum Don't kink-shame.
